# Export result of data Stack Exchange query to Excel

Tags: support, data-explorer

[What is my Archaeologist badge progress?](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/198601/what-is-my-archaeologist-badge-progress)

The link above is to a query to calculate [Archaeologist badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/157/archaeologist) progress.
Can I export the results of my query to Excel format?

Comment: Why doesn't the 'download csv' (right hand side page, just above the data table) and import into excel work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can.

[image]